# Java Mysql Backup and encrypt

Tags: java, mysql

I want to build backup feature for my java application. Although I can backup the mysql database via java application, problem is security of data and my application.

I want to protect database design and data from backup users. Since I need a backup that cannot read.

Is there any secure way to keep my application backup.

Answer (score 0):

The application layer isn't really the correct level for this.  Generally DB backup is a server thing - just make sure your script encrypts it with some standard lije openssl and you should be half way to being good.